# Problem with mapping of BLE 5.1 ATT protocol stack with winsock & winsock2 arcitechture

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, winsock, winsock2

`\`I'm developing an custom BLE client utility based on winsock & winsock2 architecture in C language system & my server I'm using ATT protocol to make my device in data mode, but whenever I trying to listen to the server then it gives continuous winsock errors 10013, 10050, 10022, 10049 etc. How do I solve this issue? I'm having an doubt that whether this two different protocol can be mapped or not? I think there is a layer mapping issue happening in the upper layer of BLE stack.

Comment: Socket programming, used for e.g. TCP and UDP over IP, is a totally different technique than BLE. How are you combining these? You need to enter much more details in your question in order for anyone to be able to answer it.

Comment: As you referred to WinSoc I guess you work on Windows platforms. On Windows WinSock does not support GATT. You have to use WinRT API instead.

Comment: @Emil No, not always. Socket is just an abstraction. It is also used for Bluetooth (Windows, Linux) and IrDA (WIndows) communication (without TCP/IP).

Comment: For Bluetooth RFComm sockets, yes, but never for (G)ATT protocol, right?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Yes, my client is running on windows..and I'm using winsock/winsock2 lib to hanshake with ATT server configured in my firmware..but every time I configured SOCKADDR_BTH data struct with my corresponding ble device host config parameter like address family, ble addr, port, device UUID etc, it always giving me diff socket errors at socket binding instance.

Comment: @SumitBhowmick Bluetooth WinSock is for Classic Bluetooth only. For BLE communication you need to use GATT legacy or WinRT API. Or third party library as Bluetooth Framework or 32feet.

Comment: @Emil Depends on platform. On Windows - yes, for RFCOMM only. On Linux for actually any: L2CAP/RFCOMM/ATT/GATT